# Supervisor alternatives on shared hosting for laravel 8 application

Tags: web, laravel-8, supervisord, pusher

I have deployed my laravel 8 application on shared hosting "Fastcomet", I've ssh access, however, I can't install supervisor to manage web-sockets, the command Sudo apt-get install supervisor always return errors, so I have contacted support and I was told that I can't make Sudo commands with the shared hosting plan and I have to move to VPS or dedicated which I can't move to at this time. Are there any alternatives for superior?

Thanks in advance any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not possible to do this sort of thing on shared hosting. SSH access is usually given to help automate certain tasks like deployments, and not for long running, business critical processes.

There are a few "hacks" that come to mind, like starting a tmux or screen session, and running a simple bash loop like:

```
while true; do mycommand; sleep 1; done;
```

However, there is a lot that can go wrong here.

Since you tagged `pusher` in the question, I assume this is also an option. Using Pusher means you don't have to run your own web-socket server, and could, instead, use theirs. This is probably the best solution, as they will "host" this for you, and guarantee the uptime.

To do this you can simply setup a pusher channel in Laravel, and install the pusher frontend library to subscribe to your channels.

You can read more about it in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels) or the [Pusher Chat App Tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chat-app-with-vue-js-and-laravel/).